# DID with anticipation

Tags: function, package, syntax-error, r-package

I am trying to build a function to compute the group time average treatment effects when individuals anticipate in the treatment. The dataset that I am using is this:

```
    year State countyreal first.treat treat_group   emp   pop  lemp  lpop
   <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  2003 CO          8001        2007           1  4729   364  8.46  5.90
 2  2004 CO          8001        2007           1  4175   364  8.34  5.90
 3  2005 CO          8001        2007           1  4189   364  8.34  5.90
 4  2006 CO          8001        2007           1  4351   364  8.38  5.90
 5  2007 CO          8001        2007           1  4304   364  8.37  5.90
 6  2003 CO          8019        2007           1   148     9  5.00  2.20
 7  2004 CO          8019        2007           1   161     9  5.08  2.20
 8  2005 CO          8019        2007           1   120     9  4.79  2.20
 9  2006 CO          8019        2007           1   147     9  4.99  2.20
10  2007 CO          8019        2007           1   139     9  4.93  2.20
```

Where I have counties and they can be untreated or treated in 2004,2006,2007.

I wrote this function:

```
compute.attgt <- function(mpdta1) {
  # pick up all groups
  groups <- unique(mpdta1$first.treat)
  
  # pick up all time periods
  time.periods <- unique(mpdta1$year)
  
  # sort the groups and drop the untreated group
  groups <- sort(groups)[-1]
  
  # sort the time periods and drop the first two
  # (can't compute treatment effects for these two
  # periods with one-period anticipation -- w/o anticipation
  # we would just drop one period here)
  time.periods <- sort(time.periods)[-c(1,2)]
  
  # drop last time period (because we don't know if
  # these units are affected by anticipation or not
  # and we are being very careful)
  # (if you were worried about more than one anticipation
  # period here, would need to drop more time periods
  # from the end)
  time.periods <- time.periods[-length(time.periods)]
  
  # list to store all group-time average treatment effects
  # that we calculate
  attgt.list <- list()
  counter <- 1
  
  # loop over all groups
  for (g in groups) {
    
    # get the correct "base" period for this group
    # (subtract 2 to avoid anticipation)
    main.base.period <- g - 2
    
    # loop over all time periods
    for (tp in time.periods) {
      
      #----------------------------------------------------
      # if it's a pre-treatment time period (used for the
      # pre-test, we need to adjust the base period)
      
      # group not treated yet
      if (tp < g) {
        # move two periods before
        base.period <- tp - 2
      } else {
        # this is a post-treatment period
        base.period <- main.base.period
      }
      #----------------------------------------------------
      
      
      
      #----------------------------------------------------
      # now, all we need to do is collect the right subset
      # of the data and estimate a 2x2 DiD
      
      # get group g and untreated group
      this.data <- subset(mpdta1, first.treat==g | first.treat==0)
      
      # get current period and base period data
      this.data <- subset(this.data, year==tp | year==base.period)
      
      # set up to compute 2x2 estimator
      lemppost <- subset(this.data, year==tp)$lemp
      lemppre <- subset(this.data, year==base.period)$lemp
      
      # dummy variable being in group g
      G <- 1*(subset(this.data, year==tp)$first.treat == g)
      
      # compute 2x2 estimator using DRDID package
      # (in this unconditional case, it would be straightforward
      # to calculate the 2x2 att just using averages, but we
      # like the DRDID package as it will work for more complicated
      # cases as well)
      attgt <- DRDID::reg_did_panel(lemppost, lemppre, G, covariates=NULL)$ATT
      
      # save results
      attgt.list[[counter]] <- list(att=attgt, group=g, time.period=tp)
      counter <- counter+1
      #----------------------------------------------------
      
    }
  }
  
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # aggregate into dynamic effects
  
  # turn results into a data.frame
  attgt.results <- do.call("rbind.data.frame", attgt.list)
  
  # add event time to the results
  attgt.results$e <- attgt.results$time.period - attgt.results$group
  
  # calculate relative sizes of each group
  # (will be used as weights)
  n.group <- sapply(groups, function(gg) nrow(subset(mpdta1, first.treat==gg)))
  # merge in group sizes
  ngroup.mat <- cbind(groups, n.group)
  attgt.results <- merge(attgt.results, ngroup.mat, by.x = "group", by.y = "groups")
  
  # event times to calculate dynamic effects
  eseq <- unique(attgt.results$e) 
  eseq <- sort(eseq)
  
  # calculate average effects by event time
  att.e <- c()
  counter <- 1
  for (this.e in eseq) {
    # get subset of results at this event time
    res.e <- subset(attgt.results, e==this.e)
    
    # calculate weights by group size
    res.e$weight <- res.e$n.group / sum(res.e$n.group)
    
    # calculate dynamic effect as weighted average
    att.e[counter] <- sum(res.e$att * res.e$weight)
    
    # on to the next one
    counter <- counter+1
  }
  
  # store dynamic effects results
  dyn.results <- cbind.data.frame(e = eseq, att.e = att.e)
  
  # return group-time average treatment effects and dynamic effects
  return(list(attgt.results=attgt.results[,c("group","att","time.period")],
              dyn.results=dyn.results))
}
```

But when I try to compute the attgt over the dataset, I get this error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = deltaY ~ -1 + int.cov, subset = D == :
variable lengths differ (found for 'int.cov')
```

How could I solve it?